# Bluetooth PAN: permanent piconet

Tags: command-line, networking, bluetooth, bluez, tcp-ip

I need to create a PAN with BlueZ 5, to form a piconet (the most basic Bluetooth network) and send TCP/IP traffic on it. I must not share internet access, it should be a simple private PAN between the two devices.

- Both master and slave have a Bluetooth® 4.0 dongle and all BlueZ 5 utilities installed, but the master is already permanently discoverable and in MASTER ACCEPT mode.
- Both devices have a compatible OS: the master uses the latest Debian, the slave uses the latest Ubuntu. Of course I have root access to both.
- Both devices can use BlueZ 5 and its utilities, `systemd` and all administrative network utilities, but not obsolete tools like `pand`.

At the end, the slave should be able to establish a connection (TCP or UDP) to a server application active in the master, automatically without the need to use a GUI.